# How to bring the TextBox in view while SIP(Virtual Keyboard) is open in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

In my application, I have a large heading and some textboxes as shown a sample below. When the text box is gets the focus the SIP(virtual keyboard) opens. Now I am able to scroll the page vertically and close the SIP and try to focus the first text box now the page jumps up and moves the textbox to the top position. How to overcome this issue?

**PS: Solution expected other than using VisualTree method.**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="Heading" Margin="40 60 0 0" FontSize="72" />
    <TextBox Margin="40 40 0 0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBox Margin="40 40 0 0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60"/>
    <TextBox Margin="40 40 0 0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60"/>
    <TextBox Margin="40 40 0 0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60"/>
    <TextBox Margin="40 40 0 0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Before scrolling SIP opening image**
[image: Before scrolling SIP opening image]
**After Scrolling SIP opening image**
[image: After Scrolling SIP opening image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `StackPanel` in a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: What would you like to happen?

Comment: sorry to get back to you delay! first time opening the SIP the screen is not getting scroll after scrolling the screen, and opening the SIP the texbox scrolls to the screen top and the SIP opens, this is not happen when opening for the first time.

Comment: You could handle the event when SIP comes up and scroll the `ScrollViewer` back I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. but at last i solved it, i just used the Height property to do this. Please do the following steps

- First create a ScrollViewer
- Indide the ScrollViewer create a container(eg: Grid/StackPanel/Border etc...) and put every controlls inside it.
- Set fixed Height for ScrollViewer and the Container (Note: Height of container should be greater than ScrollViewer's Height)

See the below Code

```
<ScrollViewer Height="500">
        <Grid Name="Container" Height="700">
            <TextBox/>
            <TextBox/>
            <TextBox/>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now you can scroll the container Grid Even the KeyBoard shown or even focus on a TextBox.